# Утечка памяти в iOS при показе модальных контроллеров

Tags: ios, xcode, память

Помогите пожалуйста. Два дня ищу в чем может быть проблема, но ничего на ум не приходит. Приложение представляет из себя более 10 View Controller соединенных между собой последовательно с помощью modal segue в графическом редакторе xcode. При запуске в симуляторе память растет на 25-35 мб за переход на след view controller. На реальном железе (ipad3) делает несколько переходов и закрывает приложение. Посмотрите пожалуйста код. В чем может быть причина? В модальных переходах или все таки в коде? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import GoogleMobileAds;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GADInterstitialDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GADBannerView  *bannerView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *roundImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *roundImageView2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *roundImageViewNavNext;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *roundImageViewNavBack;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textup;

-(IBAction)answer1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)answer2:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)answer3:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)answer4:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *but;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *but1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *but2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *but3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *but4;



@end



#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)answer1:(id)sender{

    label.text = @"text";
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:4/255.0f green:134/255.0f blue:68/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

}
-(IBAction)answer2:(id)sender{

    label.text = @"text";
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    }

}
-(IBAction)answer3:(id)sender{

    label.text = @"text";
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    }

}
-(IBAction)answer4:(id)sender{

    label.text = @"text";
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-000000/00000"];

    self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-000000/00000";
    self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
    [self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];

    CGRect oldFrame = self.textup.frame;
    self.textup.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.textup setNumberOfLines:0];
    [self.textup sizeToFit];

    CGRect newFrame = self.textup.frame;
    newFrame = CGRectMake(newFrame.origin.x, newFrame.origin.y, oldFrame.size.width, newFrame.size.height);
    self.textup.frame = newFrame;

    self.roundImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.roundImageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.roundImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.roundImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    self.roundImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.roundImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    self.roundImageView2.layer.cornerRadius = self.roundImageView2.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.roundImageView2.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.roundImageView2.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    self.roundImageView2.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.roundImageView2.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    self.roundImageViewNavNext.layer.cornerRadius = self.roundImageViewNavNext.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.roundImageViewNavNext.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.roundImageViewNavNext.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    self.roundImageViewNavNext.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.roundImageViewNavBack.layer.cornerRadius = self.roundImageViewNavBack.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.roundImageViewNavBack.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.roundImageViewNavBack.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    self.roundImageViewNavBack.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    [self.but1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"be.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.but1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.but2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"be.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.but2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bb.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.but3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"be.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.but3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bb.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.but4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"be.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.but4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bb.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}

-(IBAction)didSelectRadioButton:(id)sender
{
    for(UIButton *button in self.but){
        button.selected = NO;
    }

    UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    selectedButton.selected = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: Все контроллеры одинаковые?

Comment: Да, обычные View Controller, созданные в Storyboard. Возврат на предыдущий контроллер реализован через [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]; и память освобождается, но если переходить  1 по 10 и далее, они все остаются в памяти. На каждом View Controller много различных объектов - кнопки, изображения, текст и т/д

Comment: Вы привели код одного из контроллеров. У всех контроллеров такой же код? У класса `UIViewController` есть методы `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, `viewDidDisappear` - используйте их для освобождения памяти и чтобы инициализировать вью снова

Comment: Да, файл .h и .m подключаются почти ко всем View Controller

Comment: А вот последнего комментария я не понял совершенно. Понятное дело что есть .h и .m файлы. Это же Objective-C. У каждого контроллера они есть. Но программный код то в них разный.

Comment: Я имел ввиду что один и тот же файл .h подключается к нескольким View Controller

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому что вы описываете, это не похоже на утечку памяти: "растет на 25-35 мб за переход на след view controller" выглядит так, буд-то что-то выделяет много памяти в процессе показа контроллера.

Могу предположить, что память выделяет загрузка рекламы, попробуйте использовать один объект для загрузки полноэкранной рекламы и один объект (инстанс) для загрузки/подготовки рекламы в банере. После загрузки рекламы, показывайте её в текущем ViewController. Либо использовать для загрузки рекламы новое [API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/). Обратите внимание, что в новом API для загрузки полноэкранной рекламы используется статический метод.

Для исследования памяти используйте инструмент allocations, с помощью него можно  узнать, какие объекты создались при инициализации vc.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то API, на которое Вы дали ссылку, подходит только для iAd, я же использую Admob. Вот сделал скриншот экрана allocations http://f-picture.net/lfp/s018.radikal.ru/i512/1508/fb/0f9bf767464d.png/htm Не совсем понимаю, на что именно нужно смотреть?

Comment: Насчёт Admob, верно, не заметил. Это не отменяет рекомендации использовать один  объект для загрузки рекламы.

Comment: В allocations нужно сделать "срез" (кликнуть мышкой в перед интересующим местом и после) и кликать на "живые объекты", справа будет стек о том где этот объект создан. Вот здесь есть описание о том как пользоваться http://goo.gl/UbE31